# R: Time Series error when using stl

Tags: r, time-series, decomposition

I have the following vector:

```
vector2 <- c(24048068,26598794,21576111,20196318,26785149,27248835,23879436,29962147, 
                  27757825,30110057,39532376,31020232)
```

an turned it to a time series object

```
ts <- ts(vector, start =c(2017,06), end = c(2018,05), frequency = 12)
```

Now, I want to decompose it with the stl function.

```
ts2 <- stl(ts)
```

But I get the following error: time series is not periodic or has less than two periods. 
I know, that there already exist similar questions, but no answer could solve my problem. Does anybody has an idea?

Comment: This really has been answered many times.  You can't decompose a series using stl if you only have one year's worth of monthly data.  You could use a regression approach.  See: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tslm-decomposition/

Comment: Looking at `plot(vector2)` also doesn't appear to show any periodicity at all.